# Read own JS domain URL's cookie inside same JS script

Tags: javascript, cookies

We are loading JavaScript URL from CDN which having example domain name *cookietest.com, we want to access same domain cookies inside JS.

Example -

HTML page is hosted on www.publisher.com and inside that we have below code snippet.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookie Test</title>
</head>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='www.cookietest.com/get.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

We want to access the cookies at cookietest.com inside get.js, is there is any way to achieve this?

Comment: It is not possible to share.. Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: @PavanAndhukuri Its not cross domain, same cookietest.com JS script need to fetch there own cookietest.com domains cookies itself.